# ResultSet getDate(1)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, resultset, type-conversion

How to return `oracle.sql.DATE` from `ResultSet`?
It returns a Java date, not the ORACLE date.

I get an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Date to DATE

```
ResultSetIterator iter;
...
ResultSet rs = iter.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
    date = rs.getDate(1);
}
```

My query:

```
SELECT MIN(date_created) FROM tbl_user group by date_created;
```

Comment: show the query you execute

Comment: Try `getObject()` then cast that to `oracle.sql.DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `oracle.sql.DATE`? Do you mean `java.sql.Date`? 
What do you mean by java Date? Do you know that `java.sql.Date` is subclass of `java.util.Date`?

try this what will be the output?

```
ResultSet rs = iter.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
    date = rs.getDate(1);
    if (date instanceof java.sql.Date)
       System.out.println("sql date");
    if (date instanceof java.util.Date)
       System.out.println("util date");

}
```

**edit:**

I see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/DATE.html#DATE_java_sql_Date_) you can probably do something like this:

```
ResultSet rs = iter.getResultSet();
    if (rs.next()) {
        date = rs.getDate(1);
        if (date instanceof java.sql.Date)
           return new oracle.sql.DATE(date);
}
```

Comment: I mean  oracle.sql.DATE extends oracle.sql.Datum (ojdbc 6)

Comment: About `oracle.sql.DATE`: http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JAJDB/oracle/sql/DATE.html

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: see my edit...returned value from resultset should be `java.sql.Date` so you can type it to `java.sql.Date` and pass to constructor of `oracle.sql.DATE(java.sql.Date date)`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the ResultSet to an [`OracleResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleResultSet.html) and then use the [`getDATE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleResultSet.html#getDATE_int_) method:

```
OracleResultSet rs = (OracleResultSet)iter.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
    oracle.sql.DATE date = rs.getDATE(1);
}
```